# FullCalender.io with classic ASP

Tags: jquery, sql-server, asp-classic, fullcalendar

my apologies for this question but I'm extremely limited in the coding languages I can use - thus, you are my last bastion of support. Please see below

I want to integrate full calendar.io into my companies local intranet to show holidays for my store managers (around 800) so that area managers can gain visibility of whats happening and when.

I have a resource management system that lets them, the store managers, book holidays and is dumped onto my local server daily with a little help from Python (thank you selenium)

now, my idea was to either setup a simple connection using Python with full calendar to read events from my dB - static only.

However, my companies local webserver doesn't have Python installed and the company sees it as a risk to install anything on it as the webserver is *very* old.

Okay, cool, step 2 lets use the php file included to read the json and just dump a json file in there daily, it wouldn't be so difficult with python and pandas to setup a workflow daily.

Oh, no php either, the only thing we *can* use is asp. not asp.net, asp-classic!

so I've been toying around building basic html pages with asp-classic from my ms-sql server. and I've been able to create dynamic pages that pull from my dB (this is on a secured intranet)

please be aware that I work for a fairly large company, any changes take an extremely long time and are bogged down in politics so I won't be getting Python/php or anything installed on the webserver.

I have an ms-sql table like so:

```
ID : Varchar(255)
Event Start : datetime
Event End : datetime
Area : int
```

I imagine using something like the following would allow me to generate my events on a html page :

```
Set gobjConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set grs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
gsConnect = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=Server;Database=mydb;uid=uid,pw=pw
gobjConn.Open gsConnect


    gsSQL = "SELECT ID,[Event Start], [Event End] FROM Events WHERE Area = '" & Area& "'"
Set grs = gobjConn.Execute(gsSQL)
```

the Area number is a query string I would declare further up within my code.

from here I have no idea how to integrate this into the Jquery Full Calender.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek'
      },
      defaultDate: '2019-01-12',
      editable: true,
      navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
      eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
      events: {
        url: 'read_my_sql_dB_here',
        error: function() {
          $('#script-warning').show();
        }
      },
      loading: function(bool) {
        $('#loading').toggle(bool);
      }
    });

  });
```

sorry for the long post, I would imagine its better to be explicit rather than implicit! also please be gentle, until yesterday evening I didn't have a clue what asp-classic was (or is) and I'm a novice coder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you need to generate JSON code using classic asp. There are some JSON classes available for classic ASP ([see here](https://github.com/aimanbaharum/aspdemo/blob/master/aspjson.asp)), but the JSON code needed for FullCalender.io looks pretty simple and it would be easier to just response.write it rather than generate it using a class.

Try something like this...

events.asp:

```
<%

    Response.ContentType = "application/json"

    Dim gobjConn, grs, gsConnect, gsSQL, theData, r, Area

    ' if you're getting the area int from the querystring it's wise to
    ' check it's actually an int before inserting it into your SQL

    Area = request.QueryString("Area")

    if NOT isNumeric(Area) then
        Area = 1 ' set a default
        'response.End() ' or just use response.End() to stop the script
    else
        Area = int(Area)
    end if

    Set gobjConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set grs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    gsConnect = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=Server;Database=mydb;uid=uid,pw=pw"
    gobjConn.Open gsConnect

    gsSQL = "SELECT ID,[Event Start], [Event End] FROM Events WHERE Area = " & Area
    Set grs = gobjConn.Execute(gsSQL)

        if NOT grs.EOF then

            ' Use GetRows() to convert the recordset to to a 2D array

            theData = grs.getRows()

            ' start to build the JSON

            response.write "[" & VBcrlf

            for r = 0 to uBound(theData,2)

                ' loop through the events

                response.write "  {" & VBcrlf
                response.write "    ""id"": """ & theData(0,r) & """," & VBcrlf

                ' If you want to include a title you would need to escape the text:
                ' response.write "    ""title"": """ & JSONEncode(theData(3,r)) & """," & VBcrlf

                response.write "    ""start"": """ & theData(1,r) & """," & VBcrlf
                response.write "    ""end"": """ & theData(2,r) & """" & VBcrlf

                if r = uBound(theData,2) then
                    ' end of events, no comma
                    response.write "  }" & VBcrlf
                else
                    response.write "  }," & VBcrlf
                end if

            next

            response.write "]"

        else

            ' no events

        end if

    grs.close() : set grs = nothing ' close the recordset
    gobjConn.close() : set gobjConn = nothing ' close the connection


    ' Use this function to escape JSON text

    Function JSONEncode(ByVal val)
        val = Replace(val, "\", "\\")
        val = Replace(val, """", "\""")
        val = Replace(val, Chr(8), "\b")
        val = Replace(val, Chr(12), "\f")
        val = Replace(val, Chr(10), "\n")
        val = Replace(val, Chr(13), "\r")
        val = Replace(val, Chr(9), "\t")
        JSONEncode = Trim(val)
    End Function

%>
```

Using the [JSON class](https://github.com/rcdmk/aspJSON) linked by @lankymart:

```
<!--#include file = "jsonObject.class.asp" -->
<%

    Response.ContentType = "application/json"

    Dim gobjConn, grs, gsConnect, gsSQL, Area

    ' if you're getting the area int from the querystring it's wise to
    ' check it's actually an int before inserting it into your SQL

    Area = request.QueryString("Area")

    if NOT isNumeric(Area) then
        Area = 0 ' set a default
        'response.End() ' or just use response.End() to stop the script
    else
        Area = int(Area)
    end if

    Set gobjConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set grs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    gsConnect = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=Server;Database=mydb;uid=uid,pw=pw"
    gobjConn.Open gsConnect

    gsSQL = "SELECT ID,[Event Start], [Event End] FROM Events WHERE Area = " & Area
    Set grs = gobjConn.Execute(gsSQL)

        set JSON = New JSONarray

            JSON.LoadRecordset grs

            JSON.Write() 

        set JSON = nothing

    grs.close() : set grs = nothing ' close the recordset
    gobjConn.close() : set gobjConn = nothing ' close the connection

%>
```

In your jQuery:

```
  events: {
    url: 'events.asp',
    error: function() {
      $('#script-warning').show();
    }
  },
```

Comment: Personally used [this class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30267965/692942) in the past as it’s very intuitive and allows generation of json output direct from a `ADODB.Recordset`.

Comment: Thank you both, @Adam I'll digest your code and try and make sense of it then will attempt to implement. oh and the table design is totally under my control. I can make the Area into a string int or anything in-between.

Comment: @Datanovice wouldn't recommend going the hard coded route, consider using a class like the one I've listed which makes outputting JSON from a database query a breeze.

Comment: pardon my ignorance - in the example above(from your link) where is the json file written, locally on the webserver after querying the sql dB ?

Comment: I've had a look at the JSON class linked by @Lankymart and it's very good. I've updated my answer with another code example using the JSON class. The JSON isn't written to a file, it's output on the Classic ASP page.

Comment: If it does work remember to close the database connection. I forgot to do that in the code example I posted but have updated it now.

Comment: Hey Adam, got this  on my server - but erroring on line one `The include file 'jsonObject.class.asp' was not found.` I guess I need to download this file and add it to my dir(ignore me just done that)? also would I add the asp code an the Jquery code on the same page? in my head I would assume the seperate page would just reference the asp file via the url : events.asp (?)

Comment: You will need to download it. And yes, separate pages, you just need to reference the events.asp page in the jQuery (full domain or using parent paths)

Comment: got it working, you are an absolute legend, can't wait to show my director!

Comment: Sorry - final query I promise - if its out of the scope of this question I can create another one - my HTML page is defaulting to the default Area and not accepting a query string at the end ?Area=1 do I need add additional code into my html page as well so it references the Json file & Area specified?

Comment: The Area querystring needs to be passed to the events.asp page, it won't do anything if it's passed to just the HTML page. What you can try doing is renaming your .html page with a .asp extension, which will allow you to execute asp code on the same page as your jquery. At the top of the page repeat the asp code for retrieving the area querystring and verifying that it's a number. Then in your jquery change the url line to: `url: 'path/to/events.asp?Area=<%=Area%>'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188021/discussion-between-datanovice-and-adam).

Comment: @Adam coming back to this query just to read over your code and I have to thank you so much. I've been able to create some great Web apps using javascript and some basic asp classic. I'm taking a web coding course and I'm flying through it thanks to all the asp-classic stuff I've done. Thanks again for taking the time to help

Comment: @Datanovice That's great! I'm glad I could help, I just hope you're learning a more modern language than asp classic though ;)

Comment: @Adam, but of course! I'm learning the python Web stack in a course called 100 days of code, so much better and easier to manage!